# Encountered two children with the same key on FlatGrid('react-native-super-grid)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am rendering items from API on my application. I used FlatGrid from react-native-suprt-grid instead of using FlatList because I want a grid view of the items. While using FlatGrid I get the error: "Error: Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `.$0_1`." FlatGrid has the keyextractor property.

Here is my code :

```
return(
        <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24, }}>

      
          <SearchBar round
          searchIcon={{size:24}}
          platform={Platform.OS}
          containerStyle={{backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'}}
          backgroundColor={'#FFFFFF'}
          inputStyle={{backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'}}
          placeholder='Search for items...'
          cancelButtonTitle='Cancel'
          ></SearchBar>
        


      {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator /> : (
        <FlatGrid
        style={{marginTop:35}}
        itemDimension={130}
        spacing={10}
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
          console.log("index", index)
          return index.toString();
        }}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            // <Text style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#ffe4e1' }}>{item.name}</Text>
            // <Text style={styles.itemName} > {item.name} </Text>
            <View style={styles.gridView}>
            <CardView name= {item.name}/>
          </View>
          )
        }}
      />
      )}
    </View>
    )
}
```

I render my items from an external component CardView.

Answer (score 0):

Your key can be of type integer. You don‘t have to convert it into a string.

And ideally, each item in your data should have a unique id.

Once done, you can then try this:

keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}